# Where are savefiles stored for Sonic Mania?

Tags: windows, sonic-mania

Where are the save files for Sonic Mania stored on Windows? Can I copy save files?

It would appear to be stored under `"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Steam\userdata\<steamid>\584400\remote\SaveData.bin"`, however that file is just null zeros that's updated when the game saved, so it appears to be a decoy.

Answer (score -3):

The game stores its saves in the Steam Cloud.

Comment: So the game can't save when played offline? I find that very unlikely.